# React Native. How to set props to a view variable?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What I want to do is like:

```
var view = <View add={'something'}/>;
```

But instead I want to set the props to the variable view, like

```
var view = <View/>;
view.props.add = 'something';
```

But this does not work. It there any possible way?

Comment: You tried React.cloneElement (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I am not that familiar with RN but assume that the 1st way can solve most problems?

Comment: @iplus26 this is usefull to pass extra properties to *props.children*

Comment: @JesúsQuintana Okay, thanks for answering~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native must work in a similar way to React.

In React you user React.cloneElement to do that, for example:

```
var view = <View />
var viewWithProps = React.cloneElement(view, {add: 'something'});
```

See documentation for more information https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement